# angular.js - parse html function is taking 2000ms and much more

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to speed-up my website. This is what I found in chrome's developer tools inside Timeline/Profile JS. In contains like 150 those blue Parse HTML(in screen).

[image]

It's 50% of load time. I tested it using a tablet and this function took even 15000ms! I'm setting route provider like this:

```
var start = '<div class="important">';
var end = '</div>';
$routeProvider.when('/test', {
   template: start + 'some short text' + end
});
```

What's wrong? Complete size of website is 500kb. It has 97 scopes.

Edit: if I test website without using angular on tablet, load time is 2.5s(as I pointed above with angular it was more than 18 seconds). I'm willing to pay for solution.

I'm also adding [timeline data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08939114225862201771) that I debugged(on tablet). You can check a timeline on Chrome. Open developer console(F12). Click tab Timeline. Right click on this tab and then choose Load timeline data.

Edit 2: I'm using [angular-material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/), and I think this might the problem and this might all those parse html's because there are for example lot of buttons.

Comment: Note that the parseHTML calls are part of the Angular life cycle. How often are you using ng-repeat?

Comment: there's just one ng-repeat and it was empty(0 items) when I was taking that test(usually it has approximately 5 items)

Comment: @dontHaveName I think that unless someone has been through the same issue it's difficult to help you without seeing some actual code.

Comment: @dontHaveName I actually ran to some angularJS performance issue during one of my projects. We would need to access the application or at least see the code to have some clue about what is happening. This can happen when you have more than 10000 bindings in a single view. (Due to missuses of custom directives in our case)

Comment: Site has 97 scopes so there can' be more bindings right? And I edited my question I think it might be problem with angular-material. Because each time I do something like <md-button>text</md-button> it is probably 1 parse html

Comment: Is possible to see your code? Link to the app? 

Your initialization of router looks at least strange. So I suppose you are facing some problem which comes from misunderstanding of digest loop. 

Like calling some long time running function in expression, too much binding because of just ng-hidden parts, ng-repeat of too much fields without track by and so on ...

Comment: Make sure you don't have browser plugins running: http://run.plnkr.co/uY4ZosALiz12PFev/, also, from your screenshot it doesn't look like Angular is necessarily the cause

Comment: @dontHaveName Would you be able to make a small code sample reproducing the issue?

Comment: I asked my friend to test this site using his internet and his computer and he said it has loaded in 1 second.. So probably I just have slow internet connection(1mb/s).

Comment: how many watchers are configured on your page?

Comment: 89 - 99 on tested page(on the others, it's more but we are talking about specific page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post your code, but below the slow makers:

- Too many reflows, repaints, parseHTML
- Slow dirty checking
- Too many DOM operations

In short solutions below:

- Use directives with inline templates
- Use $templateCache
- Reuse memory instead of allocating new memory
- Use fewer watch
- Defer element creation
- Prevent large and complex ng-repeats (apply pagination for example)
- Prevent multiple (initial) requests from a page

*Where goes it wrong?*

Use a tool besides Chrome developer bar as Batarang to debug and profile your angularjs app. Download it from: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk

Read more here:

- http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/11/28/analysing-performance-of-angularjs-screens/
- http://bahmutov.calepin.co/improving-angular-web-app-performance-example.html